# how to teach beginners programming using java in an interesting way?

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

i am trying to teach some beginners how to program using java so can anyone please 
provide me with a simple but interesting and nice program that only uses if conditions, while and for loops in addition to add and subtract .

Comment: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/ for reference but if you are planning to teach then i i hope you should be aware of these sites.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion instant result are the most interesting ones when learning a programming language. When i started learning java back then i tried Turtle.java, which was a nice and easy to understand project.
You can find it here: http://www.swisseduc.ch/informatik/turtles/javaturtle/

I would recommend you taking a look at it if you want to use a third party program.

Answer (score 0):

I initially learned from the "A Guide to programming in Java" textbook using the Netbeans IDE. The first few chapters of the textbook are very simple and provide interesting and simple exercises. Learning programming can feel very overwhelming in the beginning as there is so much you don't know, so I think it's important to be structured while teaching. Agreeing with the user above, the best part about programming is having the program run and seeing the results of your work, so start with easy exercises and have them work their way up.